# AutoMapper do not map nested object with Mapper.ProjectTo

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have the following setup:

Updated to version 12.0.1 from 7.0.0

Entity class:

```cs
    public class Location
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public AddressDetails Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddressDetails
    {
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string District { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
        public string Building { get; set; }
        public string Entrance { get; set; }
        public string Floor { get; set; }
        public string Apartment { get; set; }
        public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
    }
```

Response class:

```cs
    public class LocationResponse : AuditResponse
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public AddressDetails Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddressDetails
    {
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string District { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
        public string Building { get; set; }
        public string Entrance { get; set; }
        public string Floor { get; set; }
        public string Apartment { get; set; }
        public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
    }
```

AutoMapper config:

```cs
CreateMap<Database.Entities.AddressDetails, Common.Models.Shared.AddressDetails>();
CreateMap<Location, LocationResponse>();
```

When using Mapper.ProjectTo nested object Address is not mapped but returns null

```cs
await Mapper.ProjectTo<LocationResponse>(FilterByBusinessIdAndNotDeleted(DbContext.Locations))
                        .FirstAsync(x => x.Id == id)
```

When using Mapper.Map it maps successfully

```cs
Mapper.Map<LocationResponse>(await FilterByBusinessIdAndNotDeleted(DbContext.Locations)
                    .FirstAsync(x => x.Id == id))
```

What is important to mention is that I don't have a table Address in the database I use [Owned Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities). It is flat structure but mapped by EF after extraction and I believe this is the problem that the new version of AutoMapper can't handle or needs additional setup.

Here is my configuration in OnModelCreating

```cs
builder.Entity<Location>().OwnsOne(x => x.Address,
        a =>
        {
            a.Property(x => x.Postcode).HasColumnName("Postcode");
            a.Property(x => x.Country).HasColumnName("Country");
            a.Property(x => x.City).HasColumnName("City");
            a.Property(x => x.District).HasColumnName("District");
            a.Property(x => x.Street).HasColumnName("Street");
            a.Property(x => x.StreetNumber).HasColumnName("StreetNumber");
            a.Property(x => x.Building).HasColumnName("Building");
            a.Property(x => x.Entrance).HasColumnName("Entrance");
            a.Property(x => x.Floor).HasColumnName("Floor");
            a.Property(x => x.Apartment).HasColumnName("Apartment");
            a.Property(x => x.AdditionalInformation).HasColumnName("AdditionalInformation");
        });
```

When I look at the Expression that AutoMapper generated it looks fine:

```cs
[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryRootExpression]
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && (x.BusinessId == AuthService.GetBusinessIdFromRequestDomain()))
    .Select(
        dtoLocation => new LocationResponse
        {
            Name = dtoLocation.Name,
            Address = (dtoLocation.Address == null)
                ? null
                : new AddressDetails
                {
                    Country = dtoLocation.Address.Country,
                    City = dtoLocation.Address.City,
                    Postcode = dtoLocation.Address.Postcode,
                    District = dtoLocation.Address.District,
                    Street = dtoLocation.Address.Street,
                    StreetNumber = dtoLocation.Address.StreetNumber,
                    Building = dtoLocation.Address.Building,
                    Entrance = dtoLocation.Address.Entrance,
                    Floor = dtoLocation.Address.Floor,
                    Apartment = dtoLocation.Address.Apartment,
                    AdditionalInformation = dtoLocation.Address.AdditionalInformation
                }
        })
```

Comment: It is not this. As I mentioned this couldn't be included since it's not an additional table also even if it was it wouldn't work on Mapper.Map too. FilterByBusinessIdAndNotDeleted only adds Where clause and returns IQueryable so it does not materialize the query

Comment: @Selvin should not [`ProjectTo`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#preventing-lazy-loading-select-n-1-problems) do it for you?

Comment: From the docs. `ProjectTo` must be the last call in the LINQ method chain. ORMs work with entities, not DTOs. Apply any filtering and sorting on entities and, as the last step, project to DTOs.

Comment: I have many other nested objects like that which are not OwnedEntity and with this call, it's mapped successfully

Comment: I think it's EF Core. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30996 and https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/31176. Try skipping the null check with `AllowNull`.

Comment: Where do I have to put AllowNull? I didn't find it mentioned in the GitHub issues

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thank you for pointing me in the right direction. After I tested with all properties in the Address filled as said in this issue https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30996 the object got mapped. Now I'm just looking for a workaround until it's fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having this issue until this is fixed I found a workaround.

As described in this issue https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30996. Only when all properties are not NULL it will create the object so we can add DoNotAllowNull to the AutoMapper configuration and this will always create a new object no matter the content of the object.

In AutoMapper config add this

```cs
CreateMap<Location, LocationResponse>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opt => opt.DoNotAllowNull())
```

This changes the Expression that AutoMapper generates to this

```cs
[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryRootExpression]
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && (x.BusinessId == AuthService.GetBusinessIdFromRequestDomain()))
    .Select(
        dtoLocation => new LocationResponse
        {
            Name = dtoLocation.Name,
            Address = new AddressDetails
                {
                    Country = dtoLocation.Address.Country,
                    City = dtoLocation.Address.City,
                    Postcode = dtoLocation.Address.Postcode,
                    District = dtoLocation.Address.District,
                    Street = dtoLocation.Address.Street,
                    StreetNumber = dtoLocation.Address.StreetNumber,
                    Building = dtoLocation.Address.Building,
                    Entrance = dtoLocation.Address.Entrance,
                    Floor = dtoLocation.Address.Floor,
                    Apartment = dtoLocation.Address.Apartment,
                    AdditionalInformation = dtoLocation.Address.AdditionalInformation
                }
        })
```